# Functionality of OnBackPressed inside of fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

As title says, do anyone know a way how to implement OnBackPressed functionality, just like in Activity, but in Fragment View?
It does not work when I use onKey, onKeyDown or onBackPressed in Fragment - app is closing. I would like to execute specific code when back button is pressed, because in one of fragments I have ListView, which is filled with data depending on user actions.

So when back is pressed I would like to modify values of variables ("categories" and "part"), to  fill ListView with specific data (so modify some values because user clicked something, and refresh this ListView), giving a feeling that user is going back (from parts, to categories and to close the app).

But as I mentioned, when I use onKey, onKeyDown or onBackPressed, app is closing... For instance when I include in my Fragment class:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "AAAA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Toast does not appear. With "onKeyDown" and "onKey" - the same situation... What am I doing wrong here, any ideas?

Comment: Post less code so we can help you! Share with us only your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got it.
I had to, in my "ActionBarActivity" from method "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected" move declaration of "Fragment newFragment" to outside of this method, to make it available in whole class. Then I had to include "OnBackPressed" in my "ActionBarActivity" like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!newFragment.onBackPressed()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And finally, in my Fragment I included also onBackPressed:

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (part != -1) {
        part = -1;
        toAdd = "" + category + "_";
        updateList();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And it works just like I wanted. When I push back, and when variable "part" in my Fragment is not -1, then it is executing operations defined above, returning true to "ActionBarActivity" so the app is not closing. But when, in my Fragment, variable is -1, then onBackPressed app is going back to main view, and again when user is pushing back, app is closing. That's what I wanted!
Thank You all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your very first sentance:

> as title says, do anyone know a way how to implement OnBackPressed
>   functionality, just like in Activity, but in Fragment View?

To make the back-button work with fragments you have to add them to the backstack. That should  trigger the function you want.

```
 // Create new fragment and transaction
 Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
 // and add the transaction to the back stack
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);

 // Commit the transaction
 transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, kinda works - first of all I had to change "getFragmentManager()" to "getSupportFragmentManager()". Now when I will add fragment to backstack, and press back in my app, this fragment is going back to main fragment, not closing the app. But it is not executing anything in, for instance, "onKey" method...

Comment: Hey. If one has to use getFragmentManager or getSupportFragmentNamanger depends on if you use the SupportLibrary or not. So its ok how you solved that. About the other thing, i tought you should be able to override at least onBackPressed. Ill look into this tomorrow if you didnt solve it by then. Need bed now :-)

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent register = new Intent(PollCreateCommunities_Activity.this, PollActivity.class);
    startActivity(register);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent register = new Intent(PollCreateCommunities_Activity.this, PollActivity.class);
            startActivity(register);
            return true;
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer, detailing why it solves the OP's issue. Thanks!